# Node.js - Globally installed module showing 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js for a project. I installed WebdriverIO globally using

`npm install -g webdriverio`

In one of my files, I have:

**file.js**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
```

When this file gets loaded, I get an error in the console that says:

```
Message:
    Cannot find module 'webdriverio'
Details:
    code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

If I comment out the line `var webdriverio = ...`, my code runs fine.

Considering I've installed webdriverio globally, I do not understand why I'm getting this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need it locally for your app, run `npm install webdriverio` in the root directory of your app.

Answer (score 5):

When you install globally, you should then go to the root of your app and call:

> npm link webdriverio

P.S. no need to call npm install, since you will end up having two separate installations of this module, one in global and another in your local node_modules folder

Comment: this should be the right answer; it doesn't make sense to either install it many times in different projects or install it twice (global and local)

Answer (score 4):

Node.js `require` looks into the local `node_modules` folder.

Check this link to learn how to load modules from the global modules folder:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

> If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list
>   of absolute paths, then node will search those paths for modules if
>   they are not found elsewhere. (Note: On Windows, NODE_PATH is
>   delimited by semicolons instead of colons.)

Answer (score 2):

Node looks for modules in the in`node_modules` folders only (starting with current folder and then looking in the folder above). In order to make it work, you have to install this package locally as well.

```
npm install webdriverio
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the full global path:

```
const wdio = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriverio');
```